# Why is my static array set, but my static pointer is set to NULL after my function call?

Tags: c, objective-c

So I have 3 static variables:

```
static char sys_salt[PWORD_SALT_LEN];
static char sys_hash[PWORD_HASH_LEN];
static char *sys_encoded_password;
```

And I send these 3 static variables into this a function:

```
set_hash_and_salt_for_pword(
    pword, sys_hash, sys_salt, sys_encoded_password);
```

Inside this function,

1. the salt is set by calling:

   `arc4random_buf(pword_salt, PWORD_SALT_LEN);`
2. the `sys_hash` is successfully set and remains set after my `set_hash_and_salt_for_pword` is called. This is done inside this function: `argon2_hash(...)`
3. I would expect `static char *sys_encoded_password;` to be set just like `sys_hash` is set: inside `argon_2hash` and indeed it is because I call `NSLog(...)` inside the function. (Yes—I am also using Obejctive-C. But after my function returs...the pointer is NULL again.

What is going on? Why does this pointer not persist?

Note: 2 differences I see betwees `sys_hash` and `sys_encoded_password`:

1. `sys_encoded_password` is of type `static char*` and `sys_hash` is of type: `static char sys_hash[PWORD_HASH_LEN];` (AKA—the size is predefined by macro defintion which leads to the second difference:
2. I set the size of `sys_encoded_password` inside `set_hash_and_salt_for_pword` by doing the following `malloc` call:

   `encoded_password = malloc(encoded_password_length + 1);`

The output is as follow:

```
2020-04-22 11:09:16.837705-0400 InsecureApp[31502:3180622] pword inside set_hash_and_salt_for_pword: openSesame
2020-04-22 11:09:16.838315-0400 InsecureApp[31502:3180622] salt inside set_hash_and_salt_for_pword:: \M-}b.\M-1T?\M-4\M^QW#\M^J\M-3\M-y\M-2\^V\M-O\M-E\M-p5\M-M\^R\M^Qii_<L\M-?H\M^F \M-_
2020-04-22 11:09:16.838371-0400 InsecureApp[31502:3180622] hash inside set_hash_and_salt_for_pword:: \M^K)Ϸ\M-R5}v\M-`\^FB&\^W\M^H$'\M-}b.\M-1T?\M-4\M^QW#\M^J\M-3\M-y\M-2\^V\M-O\M-E\M-p5\M-M\^R\M^Qii_<L\M-?H\M^F \M-_
2020-04-22 11:09:16.838435-0400 InsecureApp[31502:3180622] encod inside set_hash_and_salt_for_pword: $argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=2,p=1$/WIusVQ/tJFXI4qz+bIWz8XwNc0SkWlpXzxMv0iGIN8$iynPt9I1fXbgBkImF4gkJw
2020-04-22 11:09:16.838505-0400 InsecureApp[31502:3180622] pword out: openSesame
2020-04-22 11:09:16.838550-0400 InsecureApp[31502:3180622] salt out:: \M-}b.\M-1T?\M-4\M^QW#\M^J\M-3\M-y\M-2\^V\M-O\M-E\M-p5\M-M\^R\M^Qii_<L\M-?H\M^F \M-_
2020-04-22 11:09:16.838598-0400 InsecureApp[31502:3180622] hash out:: \M^K)Ϸ\M-R5}v\M-`\^FB&\^W\M^H$'\M-}b.\M-1T?\M-4\M^QW#\M^J\M-3\M-y\M-2\^V\M-O\M-E\M-p5\M-M\^R\M^Qii_<L\M-?H\M^F \M-_
2020-04-22 11:09:16.898853-0400 InsecureApp[31502:3180622] encod out: (null)
```

P.S — This is a wholly insecure local application—but I'm 1) learning C and 2) playing with the argon2 API.

Relevant code:

```
#define PWORD_SALT_LEN 32
#define PWORD_HASH_LEN 16
static char sys_salt[PWORD_SALT_LEN];
static char sys_hash[PWORD_HASH_LEN];
static char *sys_encoded_password;


int set_hash_and_salt_for_pword(
      const char *pword
    , char pword_hash[PWORD_SALT_LEN]
    , char pword_salt[PWORD_HASH_LEN]
    , char *encoded_password
){
    arc4random_buf(pword_salt, PWORD_SALT_LEN);


    uint8_t  *pword_for_argon = (uint8_t*)strdup(pword);
    uint32_t  pword_len       = (uint32_t)strlen((char*)pword_for_argon);

    uint32_t t_cost = 2;            // 1-pass computation
    uint32_t m_cost = (1<<16);      // 64 mebibytes memory usage
    uint32_t lanes  = 1;            // number of threads and lanes

    argon2_type hash_type = Argon2_id;

    size_t encoded_password_length;
    argon2_version version = ARGON2_VERSION_NUMBER;

    encoded_password_length
        = argon2_encodedlen(
              t_cost
            , m_cost
            , lanes
            , (uint32_t)PWORD_SALT_LEN
            , PWORD_HASH_LEN
            , hash_type);

    encoded_password = malloc(encoded_password_length + 1);

    if (!encoded_password) {
        // clear_internal_memory(pword_for_argon, pword_len);
        NSLog(@"could not allocate memory for hash");
    }

    // argon2id_hash_encoded(
    argon2_hash(
          t_cost
        , m_cost
        , lanes
        , pword_for_argon
        , pword_len
        , pword_salt
        , PWORD_SALT_LEN
        , pword_hash               // EXTRA
        , PWORD_HASH_LEN
        , encoded_password
        , encoded_password_length  // )
        , hash_type                // EXTRA
        , version);                // EXTRA


     NSLog(@"pword inside set_hash_and_salt_for_pword: %s", pword);
     NSLog(@"salt inside set_hash_and_salt_for_pword:: %s", pword_salt);
     NSLog(@"hash inside set_hash_and_salt_for_pword:: %s", pword_hash);
     NSLog(@"encod inside set_hash_and_salt_for_pword: %s", encoded_password);

    return 0;
}

int main(){
    /* BLAH CODE */
    char *pword = "openSesame";

    set_hash_and_salt_for_pword(
        pword, sys_hash, sys_salt, sys_encoded_password);

    NSLog(@"pword out: %s", pword);
    NSLog(@"salt out:: %s", sys_salt);
    NSLog(@"hash out:: %s", sys_hash);
    NSLog(@"encod out: %s", sys_encoded_password);

    cleanup();    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That looks like [tag:objective-c] not [tag:c].

Comment: In `C` you need pass pointer at variable, to be able to fill it. You are filling just sys_encoded_password's copy variable in call stack, instead of `sys_encoded_password`

Comment: @Cy-4AH — why are the other variables (`sys_hash` and `sys_salt`) sticky? as in they are set inside the call but this one is not

Comment: You are passing pointers at arrays, they stay the same on function output

Comment: @Cy-4AH — Got it done. f(char **) call with f(&my_static_varibale) — inside pass to other functiona as...— *variableToSet

Comment: Great! Be aware of memory leaks.

Comment: I know it's a big topic—but if there's a potential memory leak that could happen here—a link would be appreciated :) or just what should I google :)